# Import huge csv file to database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, chunks

Tutorials I am following: `https://dcblog.dev/laravel-import-large-csv-file`
I am actually following this tutorial to import a huge CSV file into the database using  `chunk()`. According to this tutorials, after slicing huge CSV records into 1000 record on each file, it should store this file in a temporary folder inside our `resources` folder and then it uses `updateOrCreate()` method to upload those files in DB in a batch. But i am only able to slice huge CSV record into 1000 records each on a file and store in the temporary folder but unable to insert into a database. It would be a great help to beginners like me if any of you kind-hearted person go through this link and identify what I am doing wrong here?

This code should store data in the database.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\Subscription;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class importSubscription extends Command
{
    protected $data;


    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'import:subscriptions';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Import Subscriptions from an array.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $path = base_path("resources/pendingsubs/*.csv");
        foreach (array_slice(glob($path),0,2) as $file) {
            $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));

            foreach($data as $row) {
                Subscription::updateOrCreate([
                    'email' => $row[0],
                ], ['email' => $row[0]]);
            }

            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. don't forget to define `$filePath` and `$chunkSize`.

If the data is too big you might have to temporarily disable memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

```
public function importCsv()
{
  $rowCount = 0;
  $chunkData = [];

  if (($fileHandle = fopen($filePath, "r")) === false) {
    return;
  }

  while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle)) !== false) {
    $chunkData[] = [
      "title" => $row[1],
      "name" => $row[2]
      // ...
    ];

    $rowCount++;

    if ($rowCount === $chunkSize) {
      Model::insert($chunkData);
      $chunkData = [];
      $rowCount = 0;
    }
  }

  if (!empty($chunkData)) {
    Model::insert($chunkData);
  }

  fclose($fileHandle);
}
```